# Connection of Service Type and Tunnel in Kubernetes and Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, service, cluster-computing, minikube, tunnel

I understand that there a different service types determining how a service is exposed within the cluster. And a tunnel with such you can access the service. But I could not finde any answers to understand the concept fully. Do I always need a tunnel to access the service and if not what is the benefit of a tunnel? Just so that I don’t have to use the LoadBalancer? And is it even right, that you can access a service and with that the cluster with a tunnel?

Visit different websites and tried it.